# Unable to retrieve correct location in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, geolocation

this is the code i wrote to retrieve the latitude, longitude but it is not working; it is showing a blank screen with the title set:

```
public class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
/**
 * Creates a new MyScreen object
 */
public MyScreen()
{     

    super(MainScreen.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);
    // Set the displayed title of the screen
    try{
    //Disabling vertical scrolling for mainscreen
    // setting the title
    Dialog.alert("before init");
    initialize();
    //creating a bit map resource from the image.
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void initialize()
{ 
   try{
       //(new LocationThread()).start();
       Dialog.alert("In init");
       Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.POWER_USAGE_LOW);
        Dialog.alert("criteria");
        BlackBerryCriteria bc=new BlackBerryCriteria(GPSInfo. GPS_MODE_NONE );          
         try {
                LocationProvider lp=LocationProvider.getInstance(criteria);
                Dialog.alert("Before if");
                if(lp !=null)
                {
                    Location loc=lp.getLocation(-1);
                    if(loc != null){
                    QualifiedCoordinates qc=loc.getQualifiedCoordinates();
                    double lat=qc.getLatitude();
                    double lon=qc.getLongitude();
                    Dialog.alert(String.valueOf(lat));
                    Dialog.alert(String.valueOf(lon));
                    }
                }
        } catch (LocationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Dialog.alert("LOcation Exception");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Dialog.alert("Null Pointer Exception");

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Dialog.alert("Interrupted Exception");

        }
   }catch(NullPointerException e){
        Dialog.alert("NullPointer Exception");
   }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Criteria specification requests Cellsite as the geolocation mode. Are you sure your provider supports this and that your device is appropriately provisioned?

Comment: I am using Blackberry 8520 with airtel provider and also i have activated GPRS for my mobile

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't answer any of my questions. The spec sheet for the 8520 says it doesn't have a GPS. Unless cellsite mode is supported by Airtel and provisioned on your service (usually an extra tarrif) location based services won't work.

Comment: Actually it worked one week back with one of my team mates. We didn't change the code and now it is giving the output like this

Comment: Then that would suggest you need to take it up with your provider.